# Mass action law and conservation of mass

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

I am starting to learn about the use of mass action law in chemistry. I am doing some exercises to practice. In particular, I am considering the reaction
$$2 X \underset{3}{\stackrel{4}{\rightleftharpoons}} Y.$$ By mass action law I have obtained the following system of ODE's
$$ \left\{
 \begin{array}{ l }
  \frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-8x^2+6y\\
  \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=4x^2-3y,
 \end{array}\label{SEDO} \right.$$

where I have used this result.
[image]

I am wondering if it is usual that the amount $x(t)+y(t)$ is not conservated.

Comment: Not usually holds true for all cases but can be conservative sometime what I thought is mass and energy equivalence theorem. I might be wrong.

Comment: Great observation!!!!

Comment: @whpowell96 I don't find where the mistake is. I have inluded the notes the result that I have followed to obtain the equations.

Comment: Op mejopa,  Plz ask this question In Chemsitry stack,  but for me the answer would follow invariance in my words. Like I am saying for the 1st one, i.e my first comment.

Comment: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are numbers of molecules (or moles), not masses of components, you can see from reaction equation that number of molecules changes during reaction

Comment: Okay,  I see Chemistry,  Is history for me. Thanks, Btw can you suggest me a good book where I can start from basics to learn chemistry.

Comment: Seriously, This the only subject,  where I cannot guess the math.